# Use "or" or "nor"?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, negation, disjunction, or-nor

I've always wondered this but never asked. Given this statement:

> Energy can be neither created nor destroyed.

Should it be *or* or *nor*? This is on Wikipedia so they are probably correct in saying *nor* but why is this so? In my opinion it sounds like it should be *or*.

The more I think of it the more I think it can be left up to interpretation or emphasis. For example, it could be interpreted to mean:

> Energy = ¬Created ∨ ¬Destroyed

or

> Energy = ¬(Created ∨ Destroyed)

Some help here?

Comment: I really like the use of logic notation to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Neither* always goes with *nor* and *either* always goes with *or*, without exception. You certainly can retain *or* in the negative sense, but not in conjunction with *neither*. Thus, your notations would be translated into complete sentences thus:

> - Energy = ¬Created ∨ ¬Destroyed ⇒ *Energy can be **neither** created **nor** destroyed.*
> - Energy = ¬(Created ∨ Destroyed) ⇒ *Energy can**not** be created **or** destroyed.*

Comment: Isn't it, "Energy can neither be created nor destroyed."?  (Note placement of be/neither.)

Comment: @KazDragon: You will probably often see both forms used. However, Jimi's version is traditionally preferred by the very precise, because it is transparent about ellipsis: in *neither destroyed nor created*, both participles are perfectly parallel; in *neither be destroyed nor created*, it is *be created* and *destroyed* that are made to be parallel, even though they are strictly speaking different parts of speech. You could say *neither be destroyed nor be created* to complete the parallel, but that wouldn't look as neat.

Comment: No! The first statement is incorrect. Energy = ¬Created ∨ ¬Destroyed means "Energy cannot be created or cannot be distroyed" (which implyes that the narrator does not know whether it cannot be created or cannot be destroyed or that there are two kinds or energy, one cannot be created, the other cannot be destroyed) which has different meaning than "Energy can be neither created nor destroyed" which is essentially the same as "Energy = ¬(Created ∨ Destroyed)" which is equal to "Energy = ¬Created ∧ ¬Destroyed" and means that energy cannot be created AND cannot be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, *nor* should be used if your phrase is already inherently negative, i.e.:

> Energy can be *neither* created *nor* destroyed.

If you had *either* there, then *or* would be used, e.g.:

> Energy can be *either* kinetic *or* potential.

Answer (score 0):

You use "**or**" when listing 2 or more elements, usually in positive statements:

> It can take 2 or 3 hours to get there by car.

Or you can use it together with "**either**":

> You can have **either** tea **or** coffee.

While you use "**nor**" when you're denying, therefore used in a sentence giving it a negative connotation and is used together with **neither**:

> **Neither** Jack **nor** Carl wanted to come to the Stadium.

Jimi gave you the exact examples from your question, and another way of using "or" in negative statements, but at least now you will understand the general rule about this.